# SAML 1.1 Token Generator and Self Signing using Java

Tags: saml, opensaml, wss4j

As a requirement I need to configure 2 enterprise applications using SAML token. 
Due to following listed constraints I need to write individual services for token generation and token signing.

The Constraints are:

1. No IdP(Identity Provider) available. No associated metadata file available.
2. Need to use SAML 1.1 version
3. Need to self-sign the SAML Response.

As part of POC I am able to generate SAML Token using 2.0 version by writing a service which is forwarding to Signing service for signing. I am able to sign it by generating certificate\keystore using Windows keytool command.

Although For SAML 1.1 Implementation using OpenSAML library I am unable to generate the SAML request message in proper format. I looked for additional libraries which could help like WSS4J which has [SAML Token Profile Generator](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/).
Also some configuration around IBM Websphere Application server ([SAML Token Generater](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_createbearertoken.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-15-3-0-1-0&lang=en)) as that is the used for hosting an application. Still could not implement the solution using the above options.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to do a SAML implementation without using a IdP Server ?
2. Can I use IBM Websphere Application Server(WAS) as IdP Server?
3. Can WAS be utilized for generating STS tokens ?
4. Any library like OpenSAML, WSS4J which can be helpful to generate & Sign SAML Tokens easily for SAML 1.1 version ?